# Error in running nfcore-sarek in EC2 by using aws batch

Tags: docker, aws-batch, nextflow, nf-core

ERROR ~ Specify correct --awsqueue and --awsregion parameters on AWSBatch!. Expression: (params.awsqueue && params.awsregion)
nextflow.config file is-

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6wMO.png)

set up batch computing environment, jobqueue, provided custom config file with -c. and stuck with same error over and over

Comment: Please post your script and errors in text using markdown rather than pictures or plain text in the future. 

The error indicates you haven't set up an appropriate AWS environment. Did you set up the account? If so, did you follow a tutorial on how to set up AWS batch for use with nextflow?